# DataGrid Row Border change if one cell of the row is selected

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a DataGrid.RowStyle, who changes the BorderBrush and BorderThickness, when the IsKeyboardFocusWithin property is true.

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
  <Style.Triggers>
   <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FFFB1818"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,1.5"/>
   </Trigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
 </Style
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

So its just work, but now i want to change the border of the row, if a cell of the row is selected. I can change the selectedcell in the program so i just need a style for this, because i dont focus the selected cell with the Keyboard/Mouse. But i dont see how to set the Trigger. Is there something like `SomeCellIsSelected`-Property in the DataGridRow ?

Pls note that i use a datagrid in `WPF` not a datagridview!

Comment: How about [this approach](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/03ed7024-1549-4953-ab42-93b8f60e64ea/datagrid-highlight-entire-row-when-selectionunit-cell?forum=wpf) using attached property? Seems working.

Comment: Nah, thanks. I just found the link, that\`s all. You can post it yourself if you want.

Comment: After some chat in the comments icebat got [this link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/03ed7024-1549-4953-ab42-93b8f60e64ea/datagrid-highlight-entire-row-when-selectionunit-cell?forum=wpf), which is working.